# Complex Integral with Absolute Value

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I have to compute this integral:

$\large{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}} dx dy \, \LARGE{ \frac{ |\frac{n}{l} (\frac{z-z_{0}}{l})^{n-1}|^{2}}{(1 + \frac{1}{4} |(\frac{z-z_{0}}{l})^{n}|^{2})^2}} $,

$n \in \Bbb{Z}, l \in \Bbb{R}, z_{0} \in \Bbb{C}, z = x+ i y $.

I'm given that the answer is $8\pi n$. I wanted to use the residue theorem, but I'm stuck on what to do with the absolute values, if the theorem is even applicable.

I'm also confused about why they have written an integral over dx and dy when the function is a complex function of z. I tried to parameterize $z$ with $r  \, e^{i\theta}$, but again got stuck with the absolute values.

Edit: Thanks, Daniel for your suggestion. I realized there was a typo in the denominator that I fixed, but the suggestion is still helpful

Steps 1 & 2: Redefine $(z-z_0)/l = \tilde{z}$ and switch to polar coordinates.

$\large{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}} dx dy \,l^{2} \, \Large{ \frac{ |\frac{n}{l} \tilde{z}^{n-1}|^{2}}{(1 + \frac{1}{4} |\tilde{z}^{n}|^{2})^2}} $

$\large{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}} dx dy \, \Large{ \frac{ n^{2} \tilde{z}^{n-1}{\tilde{z}^{*}}^{n-1}}{(1 + \frac{1}{4} \tilde{z}^{n}{\tilde{z}^{*}}^{n})^2}} $

Since $ \tilde{z}=r e^{i\phi}$, ${\tilde{z}^{*}}=re^{-i\phi}$ and ${\tilde{z}^{*}} = r^{2}/\tilde{z}$.

$\large{\int_{0}^{\infty} \, rdr \int_{0}^{2\pi}} d\phi \, \Large{ \frac{ n^2 \tilde{z}^{n-1}(\frac{r^{2}}{\tilde{z}})^{n-1}}{(1 + \frac{1}{4} \tilde{z}^{n}(\frac{r^{2}}{\tilde{z}})^{n})^{2}}} $

$\large{\int_{0}^{\infty} \, rdr \int_{0}^{2\pi}} d\phi \, \Large{ \frac{ n^2 r^{2n-2}}{(1 + \frac{1}{4} r^{2n})^{2}}} $

$\large{\int_{0}^{\infty} \, dr} 2\pi \, \Large{ \frac{ n^2 r^{2n-1}}{(1 + \frac{1}{4} r^{2n})^{2}}} $

Edit 2:

Define t = $r^{2n}$

$ {\int_{0}^{\infty} \, dt} \pi \, { \frac{ n }{(1 + \frac{1}{4} t)^{2}}} = \frac{-4}{1+\frac{1}{4}t}|_{0}^{\infty} =  4\pi n $

Edit 3:

That the answer--the problem gave me the incorrect solution.

Comment: Only *one* integral and $dxdy$? Double integral?

Comment: I think they meant integrate over all x and y, so I updated for clarity

Comment: Step 1: Say why you can without loss of generality assume that $z_0 = 0$. (This can be omitted, at the cost of less convenient notation in the following.) Step 2: Write the integral in polar coordinates, outer integral over $r$, inner over $\varphi$. Step 3: Apply the residue theorem to the inner integral. For that, write $d\varphi$ in terms of $dz$ and note that for $\lvert z\rvert = r > 0$ you have $\overline{z} = r^2/z$.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielFischer for your suggestion. I tried it out and my answer is still incorrect, and I'm unsure where I went wrong

Comment: By my outline the residue theorem would have been applied to the integral over the circle $\lvert \tilde{z}\rvert = r$ (somewhat silly, because the integrand doesn't depend on $\varphi$, computing the integral in a purely real way is the natural thing to do). To use the residue theorem for $\int_0^{\infty} \ldots\,dr$ you need to use a roundabout trick like introducing an $r^{\varepsilon}$ ($0 < \lvert \varepsilon\rvert < 1$) and let $\varepsilon \to 0$. That works, but evaluating it the real way is much simpler.

Comment: Anyway, if in the first integral of your Step 3 you make the substitution $t = r^{2n}$ and forget about complex analysis, you find that the integral is actually $4\pi \lvert n\rvert$, not $8\pi n$. [Unless I made a stupid mistake, I haven't written things down on paper.]

Comment: @DanielFischer That's much more natural, thanks! I will check the problem more closely to see if I dropped a 2 somewhere